# getParam() always returns null

Tags: php, phalcon, phalcon-routing

I'm trying to get the project id from the url using the router. Let's say this is my URL: http://boardash.test/tasks/all/7 and I want to get the 7 in my controller.

I created a router using this:

```
$router->add(
    '/tasks/:action/{project}',
    [
        'controller' => 'tasks',
        ':action'    => 1
    ]
);
```

And try to access it using:

`$this->dispatcher->getParam('project');`

But when I `var_dump()` this, it returns `null`

**What am I missing?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `:action` placeholder is not correct. Try like this:

```
$router->add(
    '/tasks/:action/{project}',
    [
        'controller' => 'tasks',
        'action'    => 1 // <-- Look here
    ]
);
```

---

**UPDATE:** after few tests it seems that it is a bug in the mixed array/short syntax when the named parameter is at the end of the route.

This works as intended and returns correct parameters.

```
// Test url: /misc/4444444/view
$router->add('/misc/{project}/:action', ['controller' => 'misc', 'action' => 2])
```

However this does not return correct value for `{project}`. It returns "view" instead of "4444444".

```
// Test url: /misc/view/4444444
$router->add('/misc/:action/{project}', ['controller' => 'misc', 'action' => 1])
```

**Syntax explained in the docs:** https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/3.2/routing#defining-mixed-parameters

I will investigate a little further later, but you may consider submitting an issue on github meanwhile.

---

**Temporary solution:** meanwhile you can use this workaround if it's urgent.

```
$router->add('/:controller/:action/:params', ['controller' => 1, 'action' => 2, 'params' => 3])

// Test url: misc/view/test-1/test-2/test-3
$this->dispatcher->getParams() // array of all
$this->dispatcher->getParam(0) // test-1
$this->dispatcher->getParam(1) // test-2
$this->dispatcher->getParam(3) // test-3
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for testing it your own. Currently, I use your temporary solution which works great. Will create an issue on github!